# Is there any difference between normal Pokemon and Totem size Pokemon that we received from Oak?

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

In Pokemon Ultra Sun and Moon, we can Collect a Totem Strickers that can we excange with Totem size Pokemon from Samson Oak.

But is there any difference between normal Pokemon and Totem size Pokemon? Like more stronger or something maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only difference is in size and weight, which affects moves such as Low Kick and Heavy Slam. Base stats, learned moves, and everything else is the same as regular Pokémon.

Comment: Is their in-game 3d model actually bigger? I have a Totem Salazzle, but I can't tell if it is bigger in that regard.

Comment: The model is bigger, yes. Just like boss Totem Pokémon.